# JavaScript function returns undefined except when debugging

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

When trying this simple code:

```
function create_folder(name, parent_ID) {
    var BM_folder = "";
    chrome.bookmarks.create({title : name, parent_id : parent_ID }, function (new_folder) {
        BM_folder = new_folder;
    });
    console.log("create folder in id   : " + BM_folder.id);
    return BM_folder.id;
}
```

I get `undefined` as output, but when I debug it works fine and I get the real bookmark ID. I have similar problems in more functions, I guess it's the same problem.

EDIT #1: fixed the vars, my real function has full strings, I simply can't post that way.

EDIT #2: thanks [Marco Bonelli](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3889449/marco-bonelli), is there a way to turn this into sync, so that I'll be able to use normal oop?

Comment: Strange how you've swapped the variable 'parent-id' with the member name 'parent-ID'. Does that work when defining JS objects?

Comment: `new-folder` this is syntax errors so your code can't even run. I suggest posting real variable names, not to confuse people.

Comment: Anyway, this is duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-to-return-the-response-from-an-ajax-call

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are several problems in your code:

1. First of all, that function **cannot** work... you're using a hypen (`-`), and variable/function names cannot contain hypens in JavaScript, so change it in something else, maybe `create_folder` or `createFolder`. That's the same for your variable `BM-folder`, and `parent-ID`. Call them `BMFolder` and `parentID`.
2. Secondly, you are creating the object to pass to `chrome.bookmarks.create()` in the wrong way: `parent-ID` is both wrong and undefined. You should do: `chrome.bookmarks.create({title: name, parentID: parentid})`.
3. Inside your function, you're calling the `chrome.bookmarks.create()` method, which is **asynchronous**: this means that the code is processed separately from the body of your function, and when the method has finished working, it will call the callback function, which you provide as second argument. Basically when calling `chrome.bookmarks.create()` you have to **wait** until it's finished to continue, because if you try to access the `BMfolder.id` variable before the callback gets called it will obviously be undefined.

Now, to summarize what I said above, I'll show the right code for to achieve you're trying to:

```
function createFolder(name, parentid) {
    chrome.bookmarks.create({title: name, parentID: parentid }, function (newFolder) {
        console.log("Created the folder with ID: " + newFolder.id);
        goOn(newFolder);
    });
}

function goOn(BMFolder) {
    console.log('Here is the folder: ', BMFolder);
    // do something...
}
```

You cannot use `return BMFolder.id`, because your function is asynchronous, so the only thing you can do to know that the bookmark folder has been created is to call another function to continue. For example, you can name it `goOn()`.

---

**EDIT:**

> Is there a way to turn this into sync, so that I'll be able to use normal oop?

**Unfortunately you cannot turn an asynchronous function into a synchronous one**. Chrome extensions' methods are **only asynchronous**, therefore you have to work on that. By the way, working asynchronously is much more efficient than working synchronously, and you should get used to this programming style, because (as said before) Chrome extensions only work asynchronously, and so do many other JS frameworks and APIs.

Comment: @oriandabud nope, chrome extensions' methods are only asynchronous

Comment: so ther is another way to wait for function other then inserting it to the local one?

Comment: Yes, you can call it without inserting it in the local one.

Comment: ?, i mean using an asyncfonction, and then catching its ending event, you have a link that can help me? like when i need 2 events to finish

Comment: then use the same function for the callback and check the data inside it